# Rails form will not send ajax on first click

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, validation

I'm looking to submit a form on rails via jQuery/AJAX. My form will not submit on the first click, rather the second click, it submits.  I am looking to run rails this way since I been told that i can get a response back from server to let me know things have been successful.  Any help would be nice.

**form validations.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('#sms_form').validate({ 

   rules: {
    phone_number: {
      required: true,
      digits: true,
      phoneUS: true,
      maxlength:10
    },
    text_message: {
      required: true,
      maxlength: 160
    },
    messages: {
      phone_number: {
        required:   "Enter a valid phone number",
        minlength: jQuery.format("Enter at least {10} characters"),
        remote:    jQuery.format("{0} is not a number")
      },
      text_message: {
        required: "text message cannot be blank"
      }
    }
  },
  submitHandler: function (form) {

    $('#sms_form').submit(function() {  
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'branch#call_sms', 
        complete: function() {
          $("#sms_status").append('<h3>Status: SENT</h3> </br>');
          $("#sms_status").append('<a href="#" id="sms_back_button" class="sms_button">back</a>');
          $("#sms_status").slideFadeToggle();
          $("#sms_form_box").slideFadeToggle();

          $('#sms_form').ajaxSubmit();
        },
        success: function() {
       // some code? 
        }
     })
      return false; // prevents normal behaviour
    });  
   } 
  });
});
```

*this is the form**

```
<%= template_start -%>
<%- 
  @text_message =  "message"
%>

<a href="#" id="text-message" class="sms_button">sms text system</a>

<div class="sms pop">

<div class="close"></div>

<%= form_for :call_sms, url: {action: "call_sms"},  
              :method => :post, :remote => true, :html => {:id => 'sms_form'} do |f| %>  
  <div id='sms_form_box'>
    <p>
      <%= f.label 'phone_number', 'phone number' %>
      <%= text_field_tag :phone_number  %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= f.label 'message', 'text message' %>
       <%= text_area_tag :text_message, @text_message, :size => '36x8' %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= f.submit "send text message", :id =>'send_sms' %>
    </p>
  </div>

  <div id='sms_status'></div>
  <% end %>
  </div>
 <%= template_end -%>
```

**This is the Controller method**

```
def call_sms
   @text_number = params[:phone_number]
   @text_message     = params[:text_message].to_s
   @sms = ShortMessagingService.new
   @sms.send(@text_number, @text_message)       

   @sms_message = @sms.sent?

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js if request.xhr?
    format.html { render :nothing => true}
  end 
end
```

Comment: Do you have an error in the javascript console? Maybe there is a conflict with the client-side validation?

Comment: A side-remark: the url does look a bit strange to me: you post to `branch#call_sms` --> is that an anchor? I think that should be `branch/call_sms`. You could also just fetch the url from the form, since rails will build the url correctly (unless you specifically not want to use it).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this happened to me also once..

Form validation, adds a span just below your form to tell you the errors, I guess.
Something like this.

```
<span for="my_text_xxx" class="help-inline"></span>
```

So, When I was typing in the text-area and trying to submit, this span was being added and since there was not error in the form, this span was not visible. and due to this my submit button was moving a bit downwards.
Once I added a margin-bottom: 10px or 20px;  to my form..

I was able to submit on one click.
This might not be your problem, Just saying though. :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was wrong.  I was wrapping my validations wrong.  This code submits on the first click.  I have a back button that generates. but it will submit twice now.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('#sms_form').validate({ 

    submitHandler: function (form) {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        debug: true,
         url: document.URL, 

         success: function() {
           $("#sms_status").append('<h3>Status: SENT</h3> </br>');
           $("#sms_status").append('<a href="#" id="sms_back_button" class="sms_button">back</a>');

          $("#sms_status").slideFadeToggle();
          $("#sms_form_box").slideFadeToggle();

          $('#sms_form').ajaxSubmit();
        }
      })

     return false; // prevents normal behaviour
   },

  rules: {
    phone_number: {
    required: true,
    digits: true,
    phoneUS: true,
    maxlength:10
  },
  text_message: {
    required: true,
    maxlength: 160
  },
  messages: {
    phone_number: {
        required:   "Enter a valid phone number",
        minlength: jQuery.format("Enter at least {10} characters"),
        remote:    jQuery.format("{0} is not a number")
    },
    text_message: {
      required: "text message cannot be blank"
     }
    }
   }
 });
});
```